# C# to check in DataSet row a key exists or not

Tags: c#, dataset

in the below code, I need to check whether the **DBMSType** exists or not.

```
string filename = @"D:\service\configfile.json";

DataSet data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(File.ReadAllText(filename));

if (data.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
{
   var n = data.Tables[0].Rows[0]["DBMSType"].ToString();

}
```

Comment: you should learn to abstract your problem. you don't want ot know if DBMSType exist, you want to know that a DataColumn with name x exists. and then it is just a matter of basic C#    alternatively you could simply catch the exception. not sure if that is very efficient though :)#

Comment: What do you mean by *"I need to check whether the DBMSType exists or not."*? Do you want to check if a column with that name exists? Or if there's a value in that column for a specific row? What is the problem with the code you've posted? Do you get a compile error? A runtime exception? Incorrect result returned? In the title you refer to a "key", but In the code you're looking at a column. Please put some effort into clarifying the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[this is the solution got working for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18208311/best-practice-to-check-if-datarow-contains-a-certain-column#answer-66278729)

so just try the below validation it is working fine

```
data.Tables[0].Columns.Contains("DBMSType")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
if (data.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0 && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data.Tables[0].Rows[0]["DBMSType"]?.ToString()))
{
   var n = data.Tables[0].Rows[0]["DBMSType"].ToString();
   ...
 }
```

Comment: I'm getting below error message 
https://ibb.co/WkbMZwg

Comment: the column name is "DBMSType" or "DBMSType1"? Send me a print to ".Rows" especifications.